# Inverse Laplace Tranform of a function involving modified Bessel functions of the second kind

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory, laplace-transform, bessel-functions, inverse-laplace

I am trying to find the inverse Laplace Transform of
$$F(\theta) = \frac{\theta ^{\alpha -\frac{1}{2}}\,{\mathrm{e}}^{\theta /2}\,\Gamma \left(\alpha \right)\,{\mathrm{K}}_{\alpha -\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{\theta }{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }\,\Gamma \left(2\,\alpha -1\right)}$$
for $\alpha \in (0, 1/2)$ wehere $K$ means the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Does anyone has any idea how I could proceed?

It should be the case, that the function of which $F$ is a Laplace transform is a probability density function.

All the best and thx in advance!

Comment: It may be useful to know that $$
K_\nu  (z) = \sqrt \pi  e^{ - z} (2z)^{\lambda  - 1/2} \Gamma (\lambda )\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - 2zt} t^{\lambda  - 1} {}_2F_1\! \left( {\nu  + \frac{1}{2}, - \nu  + \frac{1}{2};\lambda ; - t} \right)dt} 
$$
$$ for $\Re z>0$ and $\Re \lambda >0$.

Comment: We have
$$\mathcal L^{-1} {\left[
 s \mapsto s^{\alpha - 1/2} K_{\alpha - 1/2}(s) \right]}(t) =
\frac {2^{\alpha - 1/2} \sqrt \pi} {\Gamma(1 - \alpha)}
 (t^2 - 1)^{-\alpha} [t > 1]$$
for $\alpha < 1$, $\mathcal L^{-1}[F]$ is a pdf if $1/2 < \alpha < 1$.

Comment: @Maxim could it be that you somehow lost $e^{\theta/2}$?

Comment: @Gary interesting thought, thank you very much!

Comment: Consider why we can apply the time shifting property of the Laplace transform here.

Comment: @Maxim I see, you argue that the LT of the r.v. $X-C$ where $X$ has density $f$ is just $e^{sC} \mathcal{L}(f)(s)$, right?

Comment: Correct (if we define the LT of $X$ as the LT of $f_X$). In general, negative shifts require the two-sided LT because we may obtain a function which is non-zero for negative arguments, here the one-sided and the two-sided LTs will coincide.

Comment: Thx! By the way do you have a reference for the inverse LT, @Maxim?

Comment: DLMF 10.32.8 and 10.27.3 have further references. There is a derivation in Whittaker&Watson.

Comment: Wow, thank you, didn't knew about https://dlmf.nist.gov/ before! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you make the change of variable $\theta=2z$ and consider the function
$$f(z)=(2z)^{\alpha-1/2}\mathrm e^zK_{\alpha-1/2}(z)$$
Then, my version of Mathematica finds
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}(f)(t)\\=\frac{-\mathrm i~\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i\pi\alpha}}{4\pi^{3/2}}~(t(2+t))^{-\alpha}\cdot\\\Bigg[4^{\alpha}\mathrm e^{2\mathrm i\pi\alpha}\pi\Gamma(\alpha)-(t(2+t))\Gamma(-\alpha)\Gamma(2\alpha )\sin(2\pi\alpha)~\bigg(-1+{}_2F_1\left(1,-\alpha;~1-2\alpha;~\frac{-2}{t}\right)\bigg)\Bigg]$$
So good luck proving that....

Comment: It looks to be a little bit easier the way @Maxim suggested it above but thanks!